# Almost Sure Convergence and Mean Square Convergence

Tags: self-study, econometrics, convergence

Hopefully, someone could make sense of this practice question I'm trying to solve.

[image: Question Example]

In question 3 I understand that as $n$ approaches infinity $S_n$ almost surely converges to 0, therefore $S_n$ converges in probability to 0.

I don't understand why question 4 states that it does not converge in mean square to 0.

As $n$ approaches infinity the expected value of the squared difference is 0. Am I right?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

> In question 3 I understand that as N approaches infinity Sn almost surely converges to 0 therefore Sn converges in probability to 0.

Try proving it from the definition of convergence in probability directly by calculating $P(|S_n - 0| > \epsilon)$ and seeing what happens to this as you send $n\to \infty$.

> I don't understand how in question 4 it does not converge in mean square to 0.

For a fixed $n$, what is $E[(S_n-0)^2]$? What happens when you take the limit as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: it is correct that $S_n$ does not converge almost surely but it does converge in probability.  So the OPs suggested proof of (3) is wrong the result of convergence in probability is correct.

Comment: @MichaelChernick right exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You can see that $p(s=0)$ approaches 1 as $n$ goes to infinity.  Regarding convergence in mean square error, note that the expected value for $s = 1$ for every $n$.  Hence it does not converge to 0 in mean square error.